# How do I get the current directory name in a windows command prompt inside of FOR loop?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe, batch-rename

I'm using Win-10 64-bit.

Given the following directory structure on my windows machine...

```
c:\tmp\Logs_UAT\
'-> folder1
|   '-> test.txt
'-> folder2
    '-> test.txt
```

...I'm trying to rename all files in each directory by prefixing them with the directory name, to have:

```
c:\tmp\Logs_UAT\
'-> folder1
|   '-> folder1_test.txt
'-> folder2
    '-> folder2_test.txt
```

In order to achieve this, I'm looping recursively through files in the `%basedir%` using FOR and in each directory I'm getting a current directory name using the inner FOR "loop", and then doing a rename. However, current directory is usually not derived correctly. Here's the .bat file which allows to reproduce the issue:

```
@echo off

set basedir=c:\tmp\Logs_UAT

for /R %basedir% %%I in (*) DO (
cd %%~pI

for %%G in (.) do echo %%~nxG> temp.temp
set /P curdir=<temp.temp
del /f temp.temp

echo.
echo -------------------
echo %%I
dir
echo %curdir%
echo -------------------
)
```

It outputs the same value for `%curdir%` for both files:

```
C:\tmp>test.bat

-------------------
c:\tmp\Logs_UAT\folder1\test.txt
 Datenträger in Laufwerk C: ist OSDisk
 Volumeseriennummer: D280-2DC0

 Verzeichnis von C:\tmp\Logs_UAT\folder1

06.05.2020  19:29    <DIR>          .
06.05.2020  19:29    <DIR>          ..
06.05.2020  19:02                 0 test.txt
               1 Datei(en),              0 Bytes
               2 Verzeichnis(se), 291.684.151.296 Bytes frei
folder2
-------------------
.
-------------------
c:\tmp\Logs_UAT\folder2\test.txt
 Datenträger in Laufwerk C: ist OSDisk
 Volumeseriennummer: D280-2DC0

 Verzeichnis von C:\tmp\Logs_UAT\folder2

06.05.2020  19:29    <DIR>          .
06.05.2020  19:29    <DIR>          ..
06.05.2020  19:02                 0 test.txt
               1 Datei(en),              0 Bytes
               2 Verzeichnis(se), 291.684.151.296 Bytes frei
folder2
-------------------

C:\tmp\Logs_UAT\folder2>
```

I tried:

1. Fresh console window
2. Console and batch file
3. Sometimes I'm getting the first folder name and sometimes second
4. Lots of search on the internet

I'd prefer to stick to standard windows utilities as I have to distribute the script to other users which might not have the extra software.

How do I get the current directory name in a windows command prompt inside of FOR loop?

Comment: You need to use delayed expansion. [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). [For - Looping commands - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

Comment: **PowerShell** _is_ standard Windows and in **PowerShell**, this is a one-liner: `gci -File -Recurse -Depth 1 | Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}_{1}'-f $_.Directory.Name, $_.Name }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed DelayedExpansion helped, thanks DavidPostill. Here's the working script:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set basedir=c:\tmp\Logs_UAT

for /R %basedir% %%I in (*) DO (
cd %%~pI

for %%G in (.) do echo %%~nxG> temp.temp
set /P curdir=<temp.temp
del /f temp.temp

echo !curdir!
)

endlocal
```

Answer (score 2):

- For you to get the same result as in your question, in one loop:

```py
@echo off

set "_=echo\ -------------------"
for /D /R "c:\tmp\Logs_UAT" %%I in (*
)do %_% & echo\%%~nxI & dir "%%~nxI" & echo\ %%~nxI & %_%
```

- Your output:

```py
 -------------------

 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 32E8-70C5

 Directory of c:\tmp\Logs_UAT\folder1

05/06/2020  02:40 PM    <DIR>          .
05/06/2020  02:40 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/06/2020  02:41 PM                 8 test.txt
               1 File(s)              8 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   3,128,999,936 bytes free
 folder1
 -------------------
 -------------------

 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 32E8-70C5

 Directory of c:\tmp\Logs_UAT\folder2

05/06/2020  02:47 PM    <DIR>          .
05/06/2020  02:47 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/06/2020  02:48 PM                 7 folder2.txt
               1 File(s)              7 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   3,128,999,936 bytes free
 folder2
 -------------------
```

---

1. You don't need to use more than one `for` loop, use `for /D /R`, in one loop recursive in all subdirectories, and this makes `DelayedExpansion` not necessary

   - ```py
     FOR /R - Loop through files (recursively)
     FOR /D - Loop through several folders/directories
     ```
   - ```py
     The option /D /r is undocumented, but can be a useful combination,
     while it will recurse through all subfolders the wildcard will only 
     match against Folder/Directory names (not filenames)
     Note: Source linked to ss64.com
     ```
   - ```py
     Rem :: Set your folder /Directory /Recursively tree starting at "c:\tmp\Logs_UAT"
     For /D /R "c:\tmp\Logs_UAT"
     ```
2. Why need to create and delete a file `temp.temp` in the entire directory using `for /D` with any additional `for` loop? When you already have the name of the current folder in your loop (`/R`ecursive in all sub`/D`irectories) stored in the variable `%%~nxI` (and many others available expansively too), so, for to use in your looping, just use them...

   - ```py
     Use the FOR variable syntax replacement:
     %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
     %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
     %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
     ```
   - ```py
     The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:
     %~pnI       - expands %I to a path and file name only
     %~pnxI      - expands %I to a path, file name and extension only
     ```
   - ```py
     )do %_% & echo\%%~nxI & dir "%%~nxI" & echo\ %%~nxI & %_%
     ```

     **Obs**.: About using **`%%~x`** in `directory` name observation note in **`ss64.com`**:
   - ```py
     Full Stop Bug
     Although Win32 will not recognise any file or directory name that begins or ends 
     with a '.' (period/full stop) it is possible to include a Full Stop in the middle
     of a directory name and this can cause issues with FOR /D.
     ```
   - ```py
     Parameter expansion will treat a Full Stop as a file extension, so for a directory
     name like "Sample 2.6.4" the output of %%~nI will be truncated to "Sample 2.6" to
     return the whole folder name use %%I or %%~nxI
     ```
3. You don't need to use `DelayedExpansion`, you can use `cmd /v/c echo\!curdir!` or `echo\%%~nxI`

   - ```py
     By default expansion will happen just once, before each line is executed.
     The !delayed! expansion is performed each time the line is executed, or for 
     each loop in a FOR looping command.
     Note: Source linked to ss64.com
     ```

     That's exactly what your code is doing in your question (and answer), you 
     are using multiple `for` loops, where the `DelayedExpansion` will not be 
     necessary if you used a single **`for /D /R`** when using **`%%~nxI`**

     For the same result and use on a selected line, if you are using one or more 
     `for` loops, you can also enable `DelayedExpansion` at run time using 
     `cmd /v /c echo\!curdir!` expanding the variable value in that time.
   - ```py
     )do set "curdir=%%~nxI" && cmd /v /c " echo\!curdir!"
     ```
4. For get output as the same of your code output question, you can set/use a variable for your banner (`set _=echo\ ----`), adjust this to desired layout output:

   - ```py
     )do %_% & echo\%%~nxI & dir "%%~nxI" & echo\ %%~nxI & %_%
     ```

   Or, in one conventional formatting

   - ```py
     @echo off

     set "_=echo\ -------------------"

     for /D /R "c:\tmp\Logs_UAT" %%I in (*)do (

     %_%
     echo\%%~nxI
     dir "%%~nxI"
     echo\ %%~nxI
     %_%

     )
     ```
5. For one simple and short output option in one line with `for /D /R` loop, you can try:

   - ```py
     @echo off

     for /d /r "c:\tmp\Logs_UAT" %%I in (*)do set "curdir=%%~nxI" && cmd /v /c " echo\!curdir!"
     ```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[CMD /?](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[For /D Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**

  [√] **[For /R Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**

  [√] **[DelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**

Answer (score 0):

My general solution to find all levels of directories:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion EnableExtensions

::Sample BAT to find all levels directories
:: FULL current path: "G:\First our directory\Second our directory\Third. - Strange . directory\Fourth and last  directory"

:: Get full current path (could be passed as a parameter to use as subroutine)
SET ActualP=%CD%
:: Set starting counter number
SET /A Countdir=0
:: Find number of directorie levels, echoes them to console and set associated variables
FOR %%G in ("%ActualP:\=" "%") DO (SET /A "CountDir+=1"
  set "Lvl=%%G"
  set "Lvl!Countdir!=!Lvl!"
  ECHO Lvl!Countdir!:!Lvl!
  )
ECHO.
:: Check number of levels to console
ECHO Levels of directorie: %CountDir%
ECHO.
:: Get last (current) level of directory free of double quotes and echoes it to console 
:: between brackets to assure not extra chars are present
SET "LastLvl=%Lvl:"=%"
ECHO LastLvl: [%LastLvl%]
:: Just to be sure that the variables have been set:
ECHO.
ECHO Third level of directorie: %Lvl3%
PAUSE
EXIT

:: This wiil echoes to console:
::   
::   Lvl1:"G:"
::   Lvl2:"First our directory"
::   Lvl3:"Second our directory"
::   Lvl4:"Third. - Strange . directory"
::   Lvl5:"Fourth and last  directory"
::   
::   Levels of directorie: 5
::   
::   LastLvl: [Fourth and last  directory]
::   
::   Third level of directorie: "Second our directory"
::   Premere un tasto per continuare . . .
```