# Batch rename files to grandparent directory name

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, batch-rename

Directory structure looks like this:

```
D:\folder0\subdir1\scan0001.tif
D:\folder0\subdir2\scan0001.tif
D:\folder0\subdir3\scan0001.tif
D:\folder0\subdir1\RAW\raw0001.tif
D:\folder0\subdir2\RAW\raw0001.tif
D:\folder0\subdir3\RAW\raw0001.tif
```

Currently files in the RAW directory are named like

```
raw0001.tif
raw0002.tif
raw0003.tif
```

I want to rename them to

```
subdir1 raw 01.tif
subdir1 raw 02.tif
subdir1 raw 03.tif
```

I found how to rename files in `subdir#` by executing

```
ls *tif |
Foreach {$i=1} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("$($_.directory.name) scan {0:0#}.tif" -f $i++)}
```

But I get stuck how to modify above command to look at the grandparent directory (`subdir1`).

Comment: Have you read this page,10 days ago... https://superuser.com/questions/1549284/how-do-i-get-the-current-directory-name-in-a-windows-command-prompt-inside-of-fo?rq=1

Comment: @vssher, that's a .bat example. The OP here is wisely coding in **PowerShell**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will parse the file name & use the existing basename & index:

```
gci *.tif | Rename-Item -NewName {
    $_.Name -match '([^\d]+)(\d+)' | out-null
    $splat = @(
        $_.directory.parent.name,
        $matches[1],
        [Int]$matches[2]
    )
    '{0} {1} {2:00}.tif' -f $splat
}
```